# Is Bridge.net still actively being developed

Tags: bridge.net

The github source has been archived. What is the active status of the project. If it has been suspended, are there some alternative projects?

Answer (score 1):

From the official Website, [this](https://bridge.net/):

Bridge.NET is no longer under active development.
But they are also announcing a new plan to re-implement the project (with new Architecture).

Comment: The website now provides some clarification. When I asked the question going to the official website re-directed to the github repository that provided no status information.

Comment: I understand. It happens, now everything is clear.